# IE8 rendering performance on knockout template binding

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, internet-explorer-8

I have a table with a list of 100+ items and each item has 3 drop downs with a list of 100+ items in it.

I am using the below method to activate the binding on the fly when the user clicks the search button which fetches json data from an MVC app.

**Problem is IE8 takes 20x times more than Chrome rendering**.

I have followed the below ko tips in my code:

- used valueHasMutated on underlying array to reduce the observable hits
- loaded the drop downs with the single item needed to display and only when user
  mouse hovers to the drop downs loading the all items needed for the
  `select`
- disposed properly the jquery `on` events

I HAVE TO TARGET IE8 AS IT IS AN INTRANET APP AND CONTINUE USING KO FOR MY APP IS IN QUESTION DUE IE8 & KO PERFORMANCE.

`cshtml` code:

... inside a html table i have the below td for displaying drop down.

```
           <td>
                <span data-bind="attr: { id: 'type-ddpl-holder-' + RowUniqueNo() }">
                <select data-ddpl-loaded="false" class="type-ddpl">                    
                    <option data-bind="html: TypeName() ? TypeName() : '--Please select--''" selected></option>
                </select>                    
                </span>                                        
            </td>
```

...
`RowUniqueNo()` is needed for me replace the select with the `ko template` binding with the unique `dom` element id.

The intent is without using ko options binding, load the drop down with the item from json i.e. drop down with only one item.

The below ko code is in ajax success handler, which renders the above template.

```
     ko.applyBindingsToNode(document.getElementById('place-holder'),
                 { template: { name: 'def-edit-tmpl', data: vm} });
                    onDdpl();
                    var element = document.getElementById('place-holder');
                    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {                       
                        offDdpl();
                    });
```

- onDdpl function will hook to the jquery `on` event for 'hover' events which will replace the initial bound `select` controls with the ko template binding with the use of `options` binding.
- offDdpl function will be used to dispose the `on` events.

below is the template used on the `on` event

```
<script type="text/html" id="type-ddpl-tmpl">
    <select class="fl tb120w" data-ddpl-loaded="true" data-bind="options: $parent.typeList, optionsText: 'Value', optionsValue:'Key', value:$data.TypeId">                
    </select>
```

For Rendering 100 items with this approach IE8 takes 10+ seconds and Chrome takes less than a second. During the 10+ secs, IE8 is unresponsive. Any help/tips in improving the performance is really appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible for you to put something in jsFiddle that shows the issue?

Comment: thanks for looking at the issue... the code is part of the complex view model and i am not suppose to share it public forums. 
please let me know if more information you would like to see.. Thanks again.

Comment: Your problem is that IE8 takes 20x times more than Chrome rendering. How do you expect someone here to fix that problem? IE8 is not as efficient as Chrome, no answer is going to change that. The 20x factor will always remain, to some degree. Microsoft has moved on to IE11 now.